# Flair not working correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, flair

See my [SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/756941/nazik) [image]

See my [Ask Different profile](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/31683/imazik).

[image]

and the [flair](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/31683/imazik/flair) of that account

[image]

Why it appears like this?

It shows the profile picture of another beta account.

I have changed the profile picture again to solve this, but same result.

I think it is better to ask this in both SE meta and Ask Different Meta to get solution.

Comment: @Oded: after a week, the [OP Ask Different flair](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/31683/imazik/flair) is showing signs of very stale image data indeed. Note the different images being used for the default theme vs. all the other themes, something appears to be stuck here. Care to take a look?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Yep, something gone wrong with caching. I've cleared our disk caches of these, so it should sync up when the memory caches clear out.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Our disk cache cleanup jobs were not running - for some time, causing such issues. The sysadmins are on the job - I was waiting for the web server caches to clearup. I am on web05, which shows the expected flair, though it can take up to 48 hours for caches to fully clear out (depends on what web server you hit). We also have plans to address this state of affairs (incoherent caches).

Comment: @Oded: In other words, you are about to swap that `status-norepro` to `status-reproduced`? :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - completed, you mean ;)

Comment: @Oded: Didn't want to make presumptions. If the caches are *in the process* of cleaning up, I usually mark something as reproduced until it is fully cleared up myself.. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - There was another underlying cause for this. Caches not clearing out was unrelated and a ploy in misdirection applied by our computer overlords.

Comment: @Oded: I was about to come check on the status here, glad you are on the ball as well. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caching. I see the new image already:

[image: flair images are correct]

and on your Stack Overflow profile:

[image: SO profile]

Please make sure your browser cache is cleared and refresh the page.

Your Sports profile flair is indeed not reflecting the changed image, *but* these images are generated only *once* every 24-36 hours. The server has a cache too. From the Flair page:

> that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours

However, now that 1 week later your flair is still b0rken, you were quite right to come back and poke about this again. The disk caches for flair images were not being cleared. :-) Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: see the sports beta profile pic

Comment: now what happened to sports profile

Comment: ok, Iam waiting for 1 or 2 days, but then only I can accept this answer

Comment: waited for one week, nothing changed, what to do?

Comment: I see the correct [cricket bat flair](http://sports.stackexchange.com/users/753/sports-fan/flair) on sports, but your [ask different flair](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/31683/imazik/flair) is still a little confused indeed.

Comment: @Azik: I poked Oded about this, *now* there appears to be a server-side caching issue with the images indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Due to the way we were caching profile images, when generating the flair for a site, the cached profile image used in generating flair would depend on the site you hit first.

So, if you visited your sports profile, we would cache that profile image. If you then visit the apple flair page for your profile, we would pick up that cached profile image incorrectly.

I have made a change so the different profile images will get cached separately.

This is in the next build, though the changes can take up to 48 hours to propagate due to caching.

Comment: So why did you remove the [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I removed it this morning, after seeing that the issue the OP saw persisted - this was before I figured out the actual issue. I will add it back when I am confident the changes I've made have been pushed and that the issue has cleared, once the caches have also cleared...

Comment: Nice, usually devs just put "completed" before the changes take place.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Oded did too, until he discovered the issue was not, in fact, resolved. :-P Which is why I never set the status of an issue to resolved until I see that it is in actual fact, resolved and not when I think the change I made *will* resolve it. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - To my defense, I did see the correct flair generated before setting to completed. When I saw the _incorrect_ flair come up a day or two afterwards...

Comment: @Oded the jury have found you... innocent! :)

Comment: Ah, so it was a heisenbug; it depended on the observer!

Comment: @MartijnPieters - In many ways, yes. We currently have a separate file cache on each server, so it was also dependent on _which_ server you were hitting.

Comment: @Oded: \o/ I see correct flair images across all the user's SE profiles. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Yep. I am confident that I have fixed the issue, but will keep an eye on this one for another week or so, just in case.